# How to add icon to webpage tabs in blogdown

Tags: r, favicon, hugo, blogdown

How can I add a favicon to by blogdown website? I am using the [minimal](http://github.com/calintat/minimal) theme. I tried adding the line in the config.toml `favicon = imgPath` and I also attemped to move 'favicon.ico' to the static folder, but neither has worked.

Comment: @yihui-xie These points are yours: all I know about Hugo come from your bookdown!

Comment: @romles It requires effort to read the book, and type out an answer :) Not many people do both things.

Comment: @troh how did you accomplish to add `favicon.ico` to your minimal website? In which directory should I put my favicon.ico file? Thank you

Comment: @patL please see below

Comment: @troh I've tried each step above and I couldn't make it work... thank you anyway.

Comment: @patL try the pubic folder

Comment: @troh It's working now. I realize that I made a mistake with the `favicon` file. thank you!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*If you have a file named `favicon.ico` in root directory, most browsers will use it. The easiest way is to add `favicon.ico` in `static` directory (therefore, Hugo will copy it to root directory), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043648/where-do-i-put-my-favicon-with-hugo).*

Favicon is declared in `<head>` element. In `minimal` theme, the `<head>` element is defined in [header.html](http://%20minimal/layouts/partials/header.html) file.
As you can see, the `minimal` theme does not provide support for favicon.

First, check if you have a `layouts/partials/header.html` file.
If this file does not exist, copy `themes/minimal/layouts/partials/header.html` file to `layouts/partials` directory (you may have to create this directory).

You have to modify the `layouts/partials/header.html` file.
Add after opening `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ "imgPath" | relURL }}">
```

Comment: The favicon.ico in the root directory worked. I wasn't able to get the second solution to work. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you can try `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}/imgPath">`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using other themes such as [Academic](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/), you might have to create an icon instead of a `favicon.ico` file. As per instructions [here](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/customization/#website-icon), you have to create a square 512x512 pixel image named `icon.png` and place the image in your root `assets/images/` folder. For the Academic theme, the `assets` folder is located under `themes\hugo-academic` when using RStudio.

So be careful if you have a Hugo theme that does not support simply pasting the favicon.ico file in the root of the static folder.