# Change favicon and title consistently on blogdown site

Tags: r, favicon, hugo, blogdown

I am new to blogdown and haven't done any other work with website creation so apologies if this stuff seems really beginner level!

I have defined the title of my blog in `config.toml` and I've saved my favicon image in my `static` directory as `favicon.ico`. When my blog is opened, the tab shows the right icon and title. Great!

The problem is that when I copy a link to a post in a way that shows a preview, sometimes the favicon and title will default to the theme's standard ones - so simply 'Title' and the [hyde-hyde](https://github.com/htr3n/hyde-hyde) favicon. The behaviour varies a little - for e.g. in slack, both these things are back to the example, whereas in Whatsapp, it seems to keep my post's title but not the favicon.

I've tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48491948/8506921), which is how I got the favicon working in my tab, but I still have the issue with the post previews. I haven't been able to work out the second option as I don't know where the  element is in the hyde-hyde theme.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this across platforms?

I'm not sure how one would make a reproducible example of this, but if there is specific stuff (like code from certain files or more info) that would be useful let me know and I'll provide it.

Comment: [This post](https://xvrdm.github.io/2017/10/23/socialize-your-blogdown/) is a little intense, but has a lot of useful info about previews. [This](https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet) has a lot of info about favicons. If you want an example, you're welcome to look [at mine](https://github.com/alistaire47/alistaire), though these things may vary based on theme.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll check it out!