# How to change website icon in R blogdown?

Tags: r, blogdown

I modified a template in the `blogdown` package in R to build a website. Currently it shows like this in my browser:
[image]

Its icon uses a default image in the template and I want to change it. I am sure I have replaced this image file with the one I desire using the exact same file name, and committed to github. But it still shows this icon, even if this image no longer exists in the repo.

(The file I changed is `favicon.ico`. From [How to add icon to webpage tabs in blogdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491085/how-to-add-icon-to-webpage-tabs-in-blogdown) I believe this is the image used for the website icon)

Can anyone tell me where I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491085/how-to-add-icon-to-webpage-tabs-in-blogdown

Comment: You have to [hard refresh your web browser](https://fabricdigital.co.nz/blog/how-to-hard-refresh-your-browser-and-clear-cache) after you change `favicon.ico`.

Comment: It works after hard-refreshing. Thank you Yihui!